# Security Certificate Exception

Tags: security, certificate, wifi

I am dealing with a small issue of certificate. In our wifi hotspot, every user is given a different username and password. In order to access any website, after connecting to wifi, login credentials must be submitted. problem is, any client when connecting to my server, getting a warning message saying SECURITY CERTIFICATE EXCEPTION. Then we'll have 2 options; either to continue without verification or to leave the connection. We are using CENT OS 4.4 and squid proxy. I wanna remove this warning. Please help me out. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Chances are the certificate CN does not match the host. If it's self signed or doesn't utilize a proper CA (Certificate Authority) - or the CA is not known to the client you'll get this error